# javascript: access an object inside a Closure

Tags: javascript, closures

This is debug info from the Chromium debugger:

```
this.getFunc["interestingObj"]: r=>{return arguments.length?(a[e]=r,i(r),n&&o(),t):a[e]}
arguments : (...)
caller : (...)
length : 1
name : ""
__proto__ : function ()
[[FunctionLocation]] : theLib.min.js:20
[[Scopes]] : Scopes[6]
0 : Closure
1 : Closure (t.props.ap.nodes)
a : Object
  propObject: Object
```

I would like to have access to `propObject` in the last line...and see if I maybe can manipulate that.

Is it possible? If yes, how?

I tried many things, such as

```
this.getFunc["interestingObj"].propObject

this.getFunc["interestingObj"]().probOject

this.getFunc["probOject"]
```

and many more, but so far I haven't succeeded.

Comment: Try putting a debugger breakpoint inside the function, then access the field using the console.

Comment: They are internal properties, which you cannot access with JavaScript.

Comment: @trincot yeah that is what I thought...it means I can't manipulate that property to add an additional custom property I guess. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe ask a new question with the problem you want to solve, as I am sure there are other ways to achieve what you need.